# Why does Visual C++ overwrite so much extra memory on delete[]?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
int* pi = new int[1]();
delete[] pi;
```

I watch the memory around &pi (0x006F9C58) in the memory window immediately before and after the delete[] operation:

[image: before/after delete[]]

Why does it overwrite so much extra memory around the array? I thought there would be a little bit just before where the size of the array might be stored, but nothing like this ...

Comment: In debug builds, deleted/free'd memory is often overwritten to make it obvious in the debugger that the memory has been freed. Often with the byte 0xCD or short 0xFEEE

Comment: http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html

Comment: Thanks for your response David and thanks for the link Hans - very instructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate memory, there is an overhead. You are handed back a pointer to the usable part of the memory block. But the memory manager is free to use memory both before and after the block of memory returned for its overhead. This is needed to make heap allocation performance reasonable. What you are observing is perfectly normal.

I suspect that you are using the debug heap which uses rather more overhead than the release heap. And when you deallocate the memory, the debug heap manager is writing specific, predictable, memorable values to the memory to make it easier for you to spot in the debugger that you might be writing to deallocated memory. You might find it instructive to view the memory as hex.